# Draggable without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I was looking for the JavaScript code to make a div draggable, and the only things I found were that you needed to download jQuery, is there any way to make a div draggable without jQuery using JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, take the source code, copy it, attribute John Resig, now you didn't download jQuery.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/ and you don't need jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Dragging is actually quite easy. There's a number of steps to it, but here's a run-down:

- First, to make an element draggable, just add a `draggable` attribute like this:
  `<div draggable="true">`. Note that images and links are draggable by default - in some cases you may want to set `draggable="false"` attributes on them.
- Now you need to do something when they are dragged. Set a `dragstart` event listener on the element. In this event you probably want to include code like this:

```
evt.dataTransfer.clearData(); // clear any default data
evt.dataTransfer.setData("Text","This is some text");
somevar = this; // store the element being dragged
```

- Next you need to handle what happens when you drag an element over a valid target. This is the only part that's a little complicated, as there are two Events to do this with: `dragenter` and `dragover`. The first one fires when you actually enter a target, whereas the second fires like `mousemove` does. You usually want the same event for both. In this event, to make the target a valid drop point, you must call `evt.preventDefault()` and `return false` (because the default action is to not allow a drop)
- Finally, attach a `drop` event to the target element. This event will be fired when you drop the element you are dragging in the appropriate area.

Optionally, you can also add a `dragend` event to the source element. This will be fired when the element is not being dragged anymore, regardless of whether it was dropped successfully or not. There is also `dragleave` for if you move away from a drop target.

If you need further help, let me know, but I hope this has explained how to do it. And now, an extremely basic example:

```
<div id="source" draggable="true" style="background:#f88">Drag me</div>
<div id="target" style="background:#88f;padding:5px">Drop here</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var source = document.getElementById('source'),
        target = document.getElementById('target'),
        dragging = null, // the element being dragged
        addEvent = function(source,types,handler) {
            // this is just a standard cross-browser event registration function
            // it can handle more than one type at once
            var typearr = types.split(" "), l = typearr.length, i;
            for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
                if( source.addEventListener)
                    source.addEventListener(typearr[i],handler,true);
                else
                    source.attachEvent("on"+typearr[i],handler,true);
            }
        };
    addEvent(source,"dragstart",function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        evt.dataTransfer.clearData();
        dragging = this;
        setTimeout(function() {dragging.style.opacity=0.5;},1);
        // ^ tiny pause so browser can get the right drag image
    });
    addEvent(target,"dragenter dragover",function(evt) {
        if( dragging) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#8f8";
            evt = evt || window.event;
            if( evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    addEvent(target,"dragleave",function() {this.style.backgroundColor = "#88f";});
    addEvent(target,"drop",function() {
        if( dragging) {
            this.appendChild(dragging);
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#88f";
            dragging = null;
            if( evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    addEvent(source,"dragend",function() {this.style.opacity=1;});
</script>
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VGzrC/) is a Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. But you'd have to deal with the differences of the browsers.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#dnd

I highly recommend you use JQuery. There's no reason why not.

Answer (score 0):

Since jquery has been hosted by google, there is no need to *download* it, only reference it as such:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

More info about google hosted jquery here: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

However, if you are so desperate to use pure js, I *highly* recommend this tutorial:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/650/javascript-draggable-elements